# Can we tab through all radio buttons in Chrome Browser?

Tags: html

I have got an issue in Chrome Browser.During Tabbing for Radio Button's
 only selected button is getting focused. On tab press it should move to next Radio Button, but it not moving.

As googled only solution is to use 'Down Arrow' Key. May I know if any other alternative solution to move on Tab Key Press?

Issue is only in Chrome, working fine for IE and Firefox.

Comment: Some code will be very helpful.

Comment: make sure your tabindex is set like < input type="radio" tabindex=1....